# MySQL - Arithmetic operations with relations

Tags: mysql

How do I get the amount of income each employee automatically, based on how the number of employees who participated in the construction project .
Already tried this , but the error . Subquery returned more than 1 row .

```
SELECT e.name,
( SELECT( p.costs / count(r.employee_id)) 
FROM relation_employee r GROUP BY r.project_id ) AS revenue
FROM project p 
INNER JOIN relation_employee r ON p.id = r.project_id
INNER JOIN employee e ON r.employee_id = e.id
```

1. table employee 

   id INT

   name VARCHAR
2. table project

    id INT

    name VARCHAR

    costs INT
3. table relation_employee

    employee_id INT

    project_id INT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a correlated subquery in the select part you could get the employee count per project as a derived table to use in the from part, which at least to me looks a bit cleaner. The query could look like this:

```
-- revenue per employee
SELECT e.name, sum(p.costs * 1.0 / emp_count) AS revenue
FROM project p 
INNER JOIN relation_employee r ON p.id = r.project_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT project_id, count(employee_id) emp_count FROM relation_employee GROUP BY project_id) c ON c.project_id = p.id 
INNER JOIN employee e ON r.employee_id = e.id
GROUP BY e.name;

-- revenue per employee and project
SELECT 
  e.name as employee_name, 
  p.name as project_name, 
  sum(p.costs / emp_count) AS revenue
FROM project p 
INNER JOIN relation_employee r ON p.id = r.project_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT project_id, count(employee_id) emp_count FROM relation_employee GROUP BY project_id) c ON c.project_id = p.id 
INNER JOIN employee e ON r.employee_id = e.id
GROUP BY e.name, p.name;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0ed40/3)